# How to get password value in j_spring_security_check

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here is my login form

```
<form class="login-form" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post" >
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login Here</legend>

    <div class="form-group required">
      <label id="inputEmail" class="control-label col-md-4">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter email" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="inputpwd" class="control-label col-md-4">Password</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login"/></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

How can I retrieve input that we give to the password inside a class which implements UserDetailsService

```
public class LoginUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        final User user = DataLayer.queryToGetUserDetails(username);
```

return new UserDetails() {

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2059202961588104658L;

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return user.getUsername();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return user.getPassword();
        }



        //To DO for authentication.
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> auths = new java.util.ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
            auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("patient"));
            return auths;
        }
    };
}
```

}

I'm returning a value like above. So in order to do the customize authentication I need to get password field inside that class
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the UserDetails returned from the loadUserByUsername will be used to match the password you passed in using the passwordEncoder you set in your SecurityConfiguration

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

PasswordEncoder interface

```
public interface PasswordEncoder {
    String encode(CharSequence rawPassword);
    boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword);
```

rawPassword parameter is the password you passed in

Edit:

You need to have a SecurityConfiguration class as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private LoginUserDetails loginUserDetails;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("j_username") //user name form name
                .passwordParameter("j_password") //password form name
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") //form submit url
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(loginUserDetails).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

Comment: where I need to add this code...just check my code Ihave pasted my entire userLoginDetails code

Comment: <form-login login-page="/login"
                    authentication-failure-url="/error"
                    username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
                    default-target-url="/medicheck"/>

        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/sign-in?logout"/>
I have a security-config.xml like this. Do I need to create this SecurityConfiguration in addition to this

Answer (score 0):

@Controller

public class LoginUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

```
@RequestMapping("/j_spring_security_check")
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username,String password) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    final User user = DataLayer.queryToGetUserDetails(username,password);
```

}
}

Comment: j_spring_security_check is inbuilt spring security option right ? is it possible to customize like this